# How to create thread safe MessageListeners in DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

My MessageListener implementation is not thread safe.

This causes issues when i try to wire it in DefaultMessageListenerContainer with multiple consumers, since, all the consumers share the same MessageListener object.

Is there a way to overcome this problem by making the DefaultMessageListener container create multiple instances of MessageListeners, so that, MessageListener is not shared among consumer threads.

In that way each consumer thread will have its own MessageListener instance.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to support this. It is generally considered best practice to make services stateless (and thus thread-safe).

If that's not possible, you would need to create a wrapper listener; two simple approaches would be to store instances of your listener in a `ThreadLocal` or maintain a pool of objects and retrieve/return instances from/to the pool on each message.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Sorry to change my question to spring integration. But it just now striked that my requirement might be actually different than what i asked.We use Spring integration. So, DMLC is actually assigned to MessageDrivenChannelAdapter.
After MessageDrivenChannelAdapter, the message is sent to service activator. So, should i create Thread Local instances for service activator instance? In that case, can i use ThreadLocalTargetSource for ServiceActivator instance? Will we face any memory issues if we use that, as said in many blogs?

Comment: Not the service activator, but the bean it references - create a wrapper for it. I would use a pool rather than a `ThreadLocal`. Of course, the best solution is to make your service bean stateless.